# Serve static files using docker, nginx, php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx, containers

I'm working with containers in docker 
Where I have one from PHP-FPM and another from Nginx.
But I'm having problems with Nginx to serve the static files (css, js)
Return Status Code: 404 Not Found

## Nginx configuration

```
server {
  # Set the port to listen on and the server name
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  # Set the document root of the project
  root /var/www/html;

  # Set the directory index files
  index index.php;

 #Set server name
 server_name myproject;

  # Specify the default character set
  charset utf-8;

  # Specify the logging configuration
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  # Specify what happens when PHP files are requested
  location ~* \.php$ {
      #try_files $uri =404;
      #try_files /index.php = 404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass    myproject:9000;
      fastcgi_index   index.php;
      include         fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME         $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO           $fastcgi_path_info;
  }

  location / {
      index index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  } 

  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
      access_log        off;
      log_not_found     off;
     expires           360d;
     add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }

  # Specify what happens what .ht files are requested
  location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
  }
}
```

## PHP Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql 
COPY . /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 9000
```

## Nginx Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.12.2
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Do you have docker a volume in both containers to share the files?  -v mysharedvolume:/usr/share/nginx/html which is writeable and -v mysharedvolume:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro which is readonly.

Comment: @IgorDuarte  You need to add your docker compose file so that we can see what your docker environment looks like.

Comment: @IgorDuarteSS have you solved this issue? Can you share any results please?

Comment: @dskow if with docker-compose create a volume for php container for example volumename:/var/www - it won't be updated when restart docker compose, do you know how to force re-creating it?

Comment: Not sure of your question in the comment above. The default 'local' driver for volumes are like Unix mount points. The mounted file/folder hides what they mount on top of.  If you need the hidden files, you will need to mount to a different location and copy the content to the volume and then mount in the original location.  The original files will still be hidden but you will have copies of them.  The folder path will be created if it does not exist and you cannot mount a folder on top of a file.

Comment: @dskow look, you have a container with php code, and you have an nginx container. You want nginx to serve static files from php container. You create a volume at php container and than mount it to nginx container (as ro) and everything is ok. But when you update code in php container, build new image and restart your docker-compose - code/files in this container with new code won't be updated, need to remove volume before restarting docker-compose. Is there any way to solve it without removing container each time, can this code be updated automatically, or volume removed automatically on stop?

Comment: @RomaRush You can try to play with the volume options (`:cached`, `:delegated`), maybe could help.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem, cause service `nginx` can not find your web project. If you use docker-compose you can use `volume`, but if not you can add folder project in nginx Dockerfile to `/var/www/html`

#### nginx dockerfile

```
ROM nginx:1.12.2
COPY . /var/www/html/
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

#### for docker compose like this :

```
services:
  nginx:
    images: nginx:latest
    ...
    ...
    volumes:
           - ./:/var/www/html
  php:
    images: php
    ...
    ...
    volumes:
           - ./:/var/www/html
```